# Dynamically store user data

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

First, I have a table look like this:

[image: user task]

Then, from my code, I have a method to check user permission

```
  public bool HasPermission(Guid userTaskId)
```

Every time I insert new row into usertask table (by sql script), I must store it id to a constant to check its permission, as below:

```
  public static readonly Guid TaskA = new Guid("6F28B771-2E3E-47DD-9CB4-48B4130A8CBE");
  public static readonly Guid TaskB = new Guid("8B273B24-AD3A-41D6-969D-49A854B4E896");

  // Check permission
  if(HasPermission(Helper.TaskA)){
       // Do something if user has permission on task A
  }
```

The problem is my program has many tasks , and I need to store many constants. Is there anyway dynamically to check permission without store all of them by hand? Mean application allows admin user add dynamically many tasks they want, then I can check permission of all tasks  for other user.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what your question is here...

Comment: Can't you create a new table in database UsersTasksPermissions and store there the information?

Answer (score 0):

How about leveraging a `Dictionary`. You could cache all of your keys up front like this:

```
var tasks = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var selectCmd = "SELECT UserTaskId, Name FROM UserTasks";

using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    c.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectCmd, c))
    {
        // provide any parameters

        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            tasks.Add(rdr.GetString(0), rdr.GetString(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you'll need to create and store this `Dictionary` somewhere that you can get to it globally. Maybe a `Singleton` named `GlobalConfiguration`.

Then you would change the way you call `HasPermission` to just receive a `string`:

```
public bool HasPermission(string userTaskId) ...
```

Now, I think there may be one more field missing here -the `UserId`. But I don't see it at the moment. You're going to want to create a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` to house the permissions a user has. You would fill it in a very similar way to the other one.

One other thing. Right now you're accessing it by `UserTaskId`, but if it's possible, switch that around to use the `Name` instead. You could simply switch up the order the fields are selected in my example.